# Play a sound file in masm32 and to stop the other sound file at the same time

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, masm32, playsound

So I am doing a game in assembly language and I am using the `PlaySound()` function to play a background song. I want to do that after I "die" in the game, another sound file will start playing a sound file, and at the same time will stop the other background song.

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough detail.  What "PlaySound()" function?  Which version of Windows (or DOS, I suppose)?  What have you written so far?  In what way is it failing to behave in the way that you expect?

Comment: i am using win 8 i have written a lot of code because its a game. And i run the sound file like that
"invoke PlaySound,offset "the name of the file",NULL,SND_ASYNS"

Comment: If you are unwilling to share code and explain how it is failing to do what you expect it to, you may find that no one here will assist you. :)

Comment: i dont think i can send 1500 rows of code...

Comment: but i did send how do i provide a sound in the game

Comment: I'm not asking you to.  Rephrase your problem into a specific question that revolves around a small portion of your code that is not behaving in the way that you expect or that you are unsure of how to modify.

Comment: I have a game, in the main area i have a sound file that acts like the background song and all the window properties (all the window messages and etc). But out of the main area(before the main) I have a sound that i want to play, that will overcome the background sound file, and will play it and not the background sound. I know that in the playsound function there is the flags that do things like that(the "fdwSound") but I don't know which  flag should I enter to do such a thing. I hope its more clear now

Comment: PlaySound should automatically stop the last sound played by PlaySound. If it's not doing this then there's no flag that will make it do it.

Comment: Develop your understanding of an api with a high level language. Then write the asm code. Don't ask for help with code that you refuse to show. Please provide mcve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation.

[PlaySound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743680.aspx)

> pszSound
>   A string that specifies the sound to play. The maximum length, including the null terminator, is 256 characters. **If this parameter is NULL, any currently playing waveform sound is stopped.** To stop a non-waveform sound, specify SND_PURGE in the fdwSound parameter.
>
> ...
>
> fdwSound
>   Flags for playing the sound. The following values are defined.
>   ...
>   SND_ASYNC
>   The sound is played asynchronously and PlaySound returns immediately after beginning the sound. **To terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, call PlaySound with pszSound set to NULL.**

So you need to call `PlaySound()` three times - one to start the background music, one to stop it, and one to play the next sound.

```
invoke PlaySound,offset "the name of the bkgnd file",NULL,SND_ASYNC
...
invoke PlaySound,NULL,NULL,SND_ASYNC
invoke PlaySound,offset "the name of the other file",NULL,SND_ASYNC
```